# While Dataset refreshing that time i need one popup display in progress

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded, power-bi-report-server, powerbi-custom-visuals

When user open a report and if the dataset refresh for that report is in progress then display message that report data refresh is still in progress

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no option to get any popup or notification for the successful refresh. It must be viewed from the Refresh history under Dateset Settings on Power BI service. But there is option for sending refresh failure notification email.

References:
https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/report-server/configure-scheduled-refresh